# Show confirm dialog to confirm receipt of a product and leave feedback

Tags: feedback, dialog

I have an "e-commerce" mobile site where there is an option for the user to confirm he received the product and then to leave a feedback about it, something like this:

- User clicks on a button "I received the product"
- A dialog opens to confirm the action
- When the dialog closes, a field to leave a feedback takes place where it was the button
- We ask the user to leave a feedback about the purchase

I'm in doubt whether or not it's good to have this workflow, specially on the dialog box. On a initial research, about 60% of users like to leave a feedback so I think putting a dialog just creates one more barrier to those 40% who doesn't like to do it that much. But also, if the user misclick the button, the action is done.

This is not a process users are obligated to do, but it's something really important to us.

---

Is there a better approach to this scenario?

I was thinking about using the "undo this action" but the feedback can only be made once the users clearly declared he received the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing the flow by specifying which widgets you will use, which is not advisable until you are clear about what it is you want the user to do.

It looks like the primary task is **you want** the customer to confirm they received the thing they ordered.

A secondary task is **you would like** the customer to provide some feedback.

The highlighted words are the key to this. You cannot force the customer to do any of these these things. What you want and what the customer will do are things you have no control over.

However, every time you communicate with a customer (via the UI or other channels) is an opportunity to gather feedback, so you can achieve both goals at the same time, as long as the feedback stuff does not get in the way or interrupt the primary task.

Typically you are just inviting people to provide feedback, so make the trigger to do this obvious but keep it unobtrusive, and you should be ok. In this way those who want to leave feedback can do so just by clicking the Feedback trigger, while those that don't won't click the Feedback trigger.

There is probably no need for an undo feature because there is nothing to undo.

This probably illustrates why thinking about widgets (the "how") when you are thinking about the task flows (the "what") can cloud your thinking :-)